# PHP-OARA ebay api stopped working

Tags: php, api, affiliate, php-oara

This question is related to PHP-OARA library, detail link of class is https://github.com/fubralimited/php-oara/blob/67be49d7b19793941d12bc8da64cf553f069b064/Oara/Network/Publisher/Ebay.php

Few days back i have noticed that ebay api stopped working, when i debug it my calling api url redirects to something like "https://legacyepn.vip.ebay.com/" and page displays server not found.
Has anyone fixed that issue or found some other solution of it ?

Thank you for your time.

Regards,
Zubair

Comment: Did anyone got above problem, and fixed it ?

Comment: i wrote to the support team, as soon as i get an anwser i will post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received an answer from the support team.

> Dear Simon,
>
> Thank you for contacting eBay Partner Network Customer Support.
>
> We kindly inform you that the report cannot be downloaded via API as
>   of 15th January. The User Manual is unfortunately outdated.
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience this may have caused you, and
>   appreciate your understanding.

Comment: Thanks Simon, i have also checked their updated api docs and used method "Trading Api" for importing transactions but every time i send request, this response appears "<TotalNumberOfPages>0</TotalNumberOfPages>
 <TotalNumberOfEntries>0</TotalNumberOfEntries>"

Detail Api Link;
https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/index.html

Comment: I have also got response from ebay developer network, previously it was simple Get request from client but now requirement is to POST all values with content type needs to be application/x-www-form-urlencoded which were sending via URL. And it solved my issue.